# py2neo.packages.httpstream.http.SocketError: Connection refused

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

When I try to run the python file “joern-plot-ast” and output some result in the database Neo4j， I got the error "py2neo.packages.httpstream.http.SocketError: Connection refused".

```
use neo4j version: 2.1.8.
python version:2.7.
py2neo:2.0

String cmd1 = "echo \'queryNodeIndex(\"type:Function\").id\' | " +

"python /home/sun/下载/joern-tools/build/scripts-2.7/joern-lookup -g |  " +

"python /home/sun/下载/joern-tools/build/scripts-2.7/joern-plot-ast | " +

"python /home/sun/下载/joern-tools/build/scripts-2.7/joern-astlabel |  " +

 "python /home/sun/下载/joern-tools/build/scripts-2.7/joern-ast2features >" + outputfilename;

Process joernscripts = dbTime.exec((new String[]{"/bin/sh","-c", cmd1}));

joernscripts.waitFor(); BufferedReader br5 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(joernscripts.getInputStream())); 

while(br5.ready())
System.out.println(br5.readLine());
```

Actual results: see the pic.

[image]

Comment: Nothing was listening at the IP:port you tried to connect to.

Comment: I hava started the neo4j and the Ip 0.0.0.0:7474 was listening. But I still can't connect the socket.